# C# asp.net data annotation setting field to only number but not required

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a viewmodel class which I set to validate with data annotations in my project like this:

```
[Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid minimum price (e.g. 20.00)")]

    public double MinPrice { get; set; }
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid maximum price (e.g. 20.00)")]

    public double MaxPrice { get; set; }
```

What I would like to do is to make the field trigger validation only if something is entered, and that something is not a valid double number... If the field is left empty I'd just like to ignore it...

The way I did it now if I enter firstly something and then try to leave the field empty, the validation triggers and says the field is required, which is not what I want...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [RegularExpression(@"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid minimum price (e.g. 20.00)")]
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid minimum price (e.g. 20.00)")]
    public double? dub { get; set; }
```

Change your model to double? if you are going to allow nulls

Comment: Hey by the way, how would the regex work for integer value ? =)

Comment: It validates the digits after the dot only if there are digits after the dot. This is actually one of the patterns I keep in my personal safe as an old perl dev gave it to me and I use it so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'RegularExpression' instead of 'range'. Something like:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^-?[0-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,1})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid value")]
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot im testing it now, how would this look like for integer value ? :)

Comment: it's showing me that the field is required if nothing is entered?

Comment: No. no need to enter